PWA to TWA: Chromecast works on PWA but errors out on TWA
I am trying to develop TWA to be hosted on the google play store. Currently, my pwa application can utilize chromecast to cast video to smart TVs. However, when I tried to bundle the pwa into a TWA, I get the following error when trying to initialize chromecast:
error requesting session: session_error
Below is my simplified setup for chromecast in my Vue application:
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      remotePlayer: null,
      remotePlayerController: null,
      castInitialized: false,
      casting: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.__onGCastApiAvailable = (isAvailable) => {
      if (isAvailable) {
        this.initializeCastApi()
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    initializeCastApi() {
      cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().setOptions({
        // receiverApplicationId: 'DCFC1A35', // (TESTING)
        receiverApplicationId: this.audioOnly ? '6054D6F9' : '6F6AB411', // (PROD)
        // receiverApplicationId: '99574D83', // (LOCAL)
        autoJoinPolicy: chrome.cast.AutoJoinPolicy.ORIGIN_SCOPED
      })
      this.castInitialized = true

      const context = cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance()
      context.addEventListener(cast.framework.CastContextEventType.SESSION_STATE_CHANGED, (e) => {
        if (e.sessionState === 'SESSION_STARTED' || e.sessionState === 'SESSION_RESUMED') {
          this.setCasting(true)
          this.loadNewMedia()
        }
        if (e.sessionState === 'SESSION_ENDED') {
          this.setCasting(false)
        }
      })
    },
    stopCasting() {
      this.setCasting(false)
      cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance().endCurrentSession(true)
    },
    async startCast() {
      if (this.casting) {
        this.stopCasting()
        return
      }
      await cast.framework.CastContext.getInstance()
        .requestSession()
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error requesting session', error)
        })
    },
    requestSrc() {
      return {
        ...this.source
      }
    }
  }
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated
